# Are there situations where an infringer purposefully designed their product on claims when designing around them had no cost?

Tags: patent-infringement, claims, strategy

Someone told me that sometimes infringers design exactly on claims when going around them incurs no cost - for some sort of sneaky strategic reason.

Based on my own reasoning that sounds untrue - why would someone want liability. However maybe there is something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose some company might willfully infringe a patent if they are confident that they can prove the patent to be invalid. There are [other mechanisms](https://wjlta.com/2022/01/10/so-you-want-to-invalidate-a-patent-the-ptab-may-be-your-friend/) to challenge a patent's validity including [Inter Pares Reviews](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/ptab/trials/inter-partes-review) and [Post Grant Reviews](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/ptab/trials/post-grant-review). However if those mechanisms aren't available then infringing and then fighting an infringement case in court is a possibility. It would probably be a rare option if it were easy to avoid infringement.